# How to remove ID3 audio tag image (or metadata) from mp3 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, id3

FFMPEG is really a great tool. I know it can edit ID3 tags and even remove all tags in a row :

```
ffmpeg -i tagged.mp3 -map_metadata -1 untagged.mp3
```

But even after that, there's still the cover image.

I don't know how to remove it using ffmpeg. I know there's other soft out there that can do the job - like eyed3 - but what's the point to install it if ffmpeg can do it too, in one line, while encoding the audio ?

Comment: Here are a few ideas: https://superuser.com/questions/625665/how-to-remove-embedded-album-covers-from-mp3-files-via-commandline

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Strip metadata tags and remove album cover image

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map_metadata -1 output.mp3
```

- `-map 0:a` Includes only audio (omits all images). See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more details.
- `-c:a copy` Enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode so re-encoding is avoided.
- `-map_metadata -1` Omits all metadata.

Comment: Thank you, that works ! By the way I didn't want to remux it but to re-encode it for a higher compression in addition to removing the metadatas.

Comment: By the way, even if I don't need it right now, how could I add a cover picture to an mp3 with ffmpeg ? I can't find it out…

Answer (score 12):

I've tried to use codes provided by LordNeckbeard, none of them worked for my case. But this one worked:

```
ffmpeg -i tagged.mp3 -acodec copy -map 0 -map_metadata 0:s:0 notags.mp3
```

It shows now only one tag, 'TSSE' (means Encoder).

Comment: Well, `-map_metadata -1` works similarly for me (just encoder), but -- fun fact! -- it removes metadata from `.mp3`s, but NOT from `.opus`es! (to remember: first strip the ID3, then convert to Opus...)

Answer (score 4):

I tried llogan's solution with a small *castle.mp3* file and found out that its size increased from 4448 to 4797 bytes!
Further inspection in Audacity revealed that the signal has been slightly "delayed" as well - however the length of the file [*castle2.mp3*] remained the same.

[image]

After that, I used `id3v2 -D castle.mp3` to delete all mp3 tags from the file, and the filesize went down to 4320 bytes, with no other noticeable (undesired) changes.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me but the following did:

```
ffmpeg -i tagged.mp3 -write_xing 0 -id3v2_version 0 untagged.mp3
```

Comment: For me this is the only thing that works as well