# How can I skip an image error when trimming an mp3 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running the following command to get cut a 30 second section of the file

```
ffmpeg -i 'river.mp3' -ss 30 -t 30 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k 'audio_trimmed.mp3'
```

but I am getting a "Invalid PNG signature" error. Is there a way to skip the image since I don't need it and have the command run successfully?

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mp3 @ 0x7f8419010600] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 73436.
[png @ 0x7f8419812600] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFE000104A46.
[mp3 @ 0x7f8419010600] decoding for stream 1 failed
[mp3 @ 0x7f8419010600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mp3, from 'river.mp3':
  Metadata:
    genre           : Podcast
    album           : River City Church's Podcast
    artist          : Antley Fowler
    title           : Jubilee Brings Justice
    date            : 2016-08-15 10:23
  Duration: 00:28:28.07, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: png, none(pc), 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Episode Artwork
      comment         : Cover (front)
[buffer @ 0x7f8418c18de0] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0x7f8418c18de0] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
[buffer @ 0x7f8418c18de0] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0x7f8418c18de0] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7f8418c18ee0] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: I didn't know I could ask a super user. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just select the audio only by adding the `-map 0:a` option. Alternatively you could use `-vn` to disable any video streams, but I prefer `-map` as it is more flexible. See [`-map` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for more info.

If you want to avoid re-encoding and just re-mux instead then use `-c:a copy` instead of `-c:a libmp3lame`. See [stream copy documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) for more info.

Comment: Can you please elaborate example hoe to skip png error without re-encoding or how to select audio only ? I have a mp3 file which on trimming shows me same error.

Comment: Your this solution made my day thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/20202233/5996106