# FFmpeg adds its own metadata - encoder: Lavf58.20.100

Tags: ffmpeg

I've tried to apply the following [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20202233/2146346) on the `flac` files:

```
for x in *.flac; do
  ffmpeg -i "$x" -map 0:a -codec:a copy -map_metadata -1 clean_"$x";
done
```

But it seems, that `ffmpeg` though removes most `metadata`, it also adds its own *fingerprint*.

Why does it add this tag? What is the best way to get rid of it?

[image: VLC reveals encoder metadata tag]

Comment: Ever figure anything out with this?

Comment: Nope, still waiting for answers...

Comment: Well I have a similar question so if you ever track down an answer be sure to post it here!

Comment: Does mat2 do what you need? https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2

Comment: @VladimirNikishkin Thank you for the suggestion! However regardless whether the `mat2` can do the intended job, I still would like to understand the purpose/circumstances of the `Lavf58.20.100` tag when using `FFmpeg`.

Comment: Not very sure, but man ffmpeg says that "If metadata specifier is omitted, it defaults to global". Maybe it is a stream, chapter, or program metadata?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.narkive.com/EAjF25dp/encoder-lavf it's displaying the version of libavformat for debug purposes.

```
Post by Leo Izen
  When I encode a video file it adds metadata that says
  Encoder: Lavf52.94.0
  I assume this means *L*ib*avf*ormat version 52.94.0. Why is this added? Is
  it to brag that the video file was muxed with libavformat, or does it have
  some productive reason?
It's not a "brag", it's primarily for debugging. If the file is
broken in some way, it's nice to know what version of libavformat
muxed it.
 
Jason
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415853/problems-with-modifying-encoder-metadata-with-ffmpeg#57418059) deals with changing the encoder metadata.

I've just tried it, and using `-metadata:g encoder_tool=" "` does sets the encoder tag to a single space, but that seems to be the best we can get.

Using `""` does stills adds the default FFMPEG encoder tag.